# How to make git fork match all upstream branches, tags, refs, and objects

Tags: bash, git, github, version-control

I'm working on some SCM tasks regarding branching a GitHub repo. I need a fork of this repo for testing SCM scripts. However, the test fork of mine gets out of sync with the upstream repo. **How can I force a fork to match all branches, tags, refs, and objects of the upstream?**

I need all branches moved to match the upstream. If any branches exists on the fork that are not on upstream, I need them deleted. I need all tags on the upstream synced to the fork. etc.

Unfortunately using the GitHub API to delete the repo and re-fork doesn't suffice since it causes downstream issues with Jenkins polling the repo. Right now I have a complicated script that sets the upstream, reads the upstream branch shas, deletes and recreates all branches, etc. Hoping there is a simpler approach to this before I implement tag syncing as well.

Comment: Can you not pull all changes from upstream and push them to the fork using `--mirror`?